# Why the read() and the get() methods of the std::wistream read byte-width character?

Tags: c++, iostream, std

I'm trying to get if a file has the Unicode BOM at its beginning. I prefer to use the `iostream` standard library. I tried to solve this task as follows:

```
std::wifstream str(filename);
wchar_t bom;
str.get(bom);
```

I assumed that because of the `wchar_t` characters has two bytes size, this code should read the first two bytes from the file, but it reads only the first `0xFF` byte.

I understand, this can be solved via the "ordinary" stream, but I have the academical interest: why the given code returns one byte only?

Comment: There are too many unknowns. What is your OS, compiler, standard library, and encoding used for the file?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I thought, this shouldn't influence on the result, and that's why I chose the standard library... Encoding of the file may be ANSI or Unicode and I need to detect the actual one.

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding. "ANSI" is not an encoding. "shouldn't" is a pipe dream. I assume you are on Windows, is this correct?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ASCII and UTF-16. Yes, Windows and MSVC.

Comment: ASCII files do not have BOM.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yes, you are right. And I want to check, if the file contains it.

Answer (score 1):

`basic_istream::get` tries to read one character from a stream and convert it to whatever type `basic_istream` is templated on.

What constitutes a character in a stream (the character encoding of the stream) is determined by the locale, not by the type `basic_istream` is templated on.

Thus, if you need to impose a 16-bit character encoding, you need to imbue a C++ locale with 16-bit character encoding in the stream, regardless of whether it is `ifstream` or `wifstream`. As far as I know, there are no 16-bit locales built into Windows. You may construct such C++ locale from a system-supplied locale by adding a `codecvt` facet, for example like this:

```
std::wifstream str(filename);
str.imbue(std::locale(str.getloc(), 
                      new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, 
                                             std::codecvt_mode::little_endian>));
```

Skip `std::codecvt_mode::little_endian` if your encoding is big endian. You can also skip the BOM by using `std::codecvt_mode::consume_header`.

`std::codecvt_utf16` is deprecated since C++17, so you are on your own if you decide to use it. You can also build your own `codecvt` facet.

Comment: I knew about the `std::codecvt`, and I already use it. But you answered another question, not mine.

Comment: Added info relevant to your question.